# How can I assign a boolean value to a checkbox using React and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, checkbox, boolean

I'm working on a to do list project and I'm trying to assign a boolean value to my checkbox. When I array map my toDos, I am seeing my checkbox object return 'on' when it is not checked, and a 'Synthetic Base Event' when it is checked. (see photo below)
[image: array picture]

Here is the component for the checkbox inside my "to-do-item"

```
    <div className="checkbox-title-container">
    <div className="check-title-div">
      <div>
        <input
          checked={agreement}
          type="checkbox"
          id="checkbox"
          onChange={props.handleCheck}
          onClick={handleCheck}
        />
      </div>
```

The onClick function for the checkbox

```
  function ToDoItem(props: {
  toDo: ToDo;
  onDeleteToDo: any;
  prioritySelect: any;
  handleCheck: any;
}) {const [agreement, setAgreement] = useState<boolean>(false);
const handleCheck = () => {
  let agreement:boolean = true;
  setAgreement( !agreement );
}
```

I am also calling another function that I am console logging the array into my Chrome dev tools window on the onChange function in my component, I'd like to combine both (function above and the one below) for onChange function but if I add the handleCheck function above to the one below it becomes out of scope.

```
            handleCheck={function (updatedCheck: any) {
            const doneToDos = toDos.map((x) => x === toDoItem ? ({ ...x, 
            checked: updatedCheck} as any) : x);
            console.log(doneToDos);
```

How can I assign a boolean value to the checkbox to verify if a particular to-do-item is checked? Why is it returning a SyntheticBaseEvent? Why is an unchecked box 'on'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I assign a boolean value to the checkbox to verify if a particular to-do-item is checked?

The normal way is to read the [`event.currentTarget.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties_that_apply_only_to_elements_of_type_checkbox_or_radio) property:

- [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is the parameter received by the event listener (in your code you call it `updatedCheck`)
- [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is the DOM node that emits the event
- [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties_that_apply_only_to_elements_of_type_checkbox_or_radio) reflects the checkbox ticked state

---

> Why is it returning a SyntheticBaseEvent?

As mentioned above, we normally receive an `Event` as argument of an event listener. But React proxies/wraps them with a [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) as a way to normalize behaviour across browsers. 99% of the time you can use it like an `Event`.

---

> Why is an unchecked box 'on'?

In your event listener, when you do:

```
const doneToDos = toDos.map(
  (x) => x === toDoItem
  ? ({
      ...x, 
      checked: updatedCheck // Replace checked property by the updatedCheck argument
    } as any)
  : x // Return toDo as-is if not toDoItem
);
console.log(doneToDos);
```

...you are very probably logging the state of your `toDos`, with `checked` being replaced by the argument if the toDo is your toDoItem, and no change at all otherwise (irrespective whether it is checked or not). So the `"on"` value must come from your own code somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are right! The 'on' is being returned from my code somewhere because I am able to return a boolean value when I did event.currentTarget.checked!!